# axios Vuejs undefined response

Tags: vue.js, heroku, axios

I am newby using axios and I trying to make the below call but I am getting an undefined response error

```
axios.get('https://galaxybank-atm.herokuapp.com/galaxybank/validateCard', {
          params: {
            card: 123456789,
            pin: 1234
          },
          responseType: 'json',
          timeout: 10000
        })
        .then(function (response) {
          console.log(response);
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
          console.log(error);
        })
        .then(function () {
          // always executed
        });

         console.log(this.info)

       } catch (error) {
          console.log(error)
       }
```

The url:

https://galaxybank-atm.herokuapp.com/galaxybank/validateCard?card=123456789&pin=1234

is accessible and giving as a response a json

I am getting the error:

```
[object Error] {
  config: Object {
    adapter: function(e){return new Promise(function(t,f){var p=e.data,d=e.headers;r.isFormData(p)&&delete d["Content-Type"];var l=new XMLHttpRequest,h="onreadystatechange",m=!1;if("undefined"==typeof window||!window.XDomainRequest||"withCredentials"in l||a(e.url)||(l=new window.XDomainRequest,h="onload",m=!0,l.onprogress=function(){},l.ontimeout=function(){}),e.auth){var y=e.auth.username||"",w=e.auth.password||"";d.Authorization="Basic "+c(y+":"+w)}if(l.open(e.method.toUpperCase(),s(e.url,e.params,e.paramsSerializer),!0),l.timeout=e.timeout,l[h]=function(){if(l&&(4===l.readyState||m)&&(0!==l.status||l.responseURL&&0===l.responseURL.indexOf("file:"))){var n="getAllResponseHeaders"in l?i(l.getAllResponseHeaders()):null,r=e.responseType&&"text"!==e.responseType?l.response:l.responseText,s={data:r,status:1223===l.status?204:l.status,statusText:1223===l.status?"No Content":l.statusText,headers:n,config:e,request:l};o(t,f,s),l=null}},l.onerror=function(){f(u("Network Error",e)),l=null},l.ontimeout=function(){f(u("timeout of "+e.timeout+"ms exceeded",e,"ECONNABORTED")),l=null},r.isStandardBrowserEnv()){var g=n(15),v=(e.withCredentials||a(e.url))&&e.xsrfCookieName?g.read(e.xsrfCookieName):void 0;v&&(d[e.xsrfHeaderName]=v)}if("setRequestHeader"in l&&r.forEach(d,function(e,t){"undefined"==typeof p&&"content-type"===t.toLowerCase()?delete d[t]:l.setRequestHeader(t,e)}),e.withCredentials&&(l.withCredentials=!0),e.responseType)try{l.responseType=e.responseType}catch(e){if("json"!==l.responseType)throw e}"function"==typeof e.onDownloadProgress&&l.addEventListener("progress",e.onDownloadProgress),"function"==typeof e.onUploadProgress&&l.upload&&l.upload.addEventListener("progress",e.onUploadProgress),e.cancelToken&&e.cancelToken.promise.then(function(e){l&&(l.abort(),f(e),l=null)}),void 0===p&&(p=null),l.send(p)})},
    data: undefined,
    headers: Object {},
    maxContentLength: -1,
    method: "get",
    params: Object {},
    responseType: "json",
    timeout: 10000,
    transformRequest: Object {},
    transformResponse: Object {},
    url: "https://galaxybank-atm.herokuapp.com/galaxybank/validateCard",
    validateStatus: function(e){return e>=200&&e<300},
    xsrfCookieName: "XSRF-TOKEN",
    xsrfHeaderName: "X-XSRF-TOKEN"
  },
  response: undefined
}
```

Comment: pls post the exact error

Comment: @ShivamSingh I just add the error

Comment: There should be a CORS error in your browser console.  CORS prevents cross-origin requests unless a server has enabled them.  If you have control over your server, you can enable CORS.  If using a different origin to make a request to a server without CORS enabled, it has to be done from a backend like Node, rather than a browser.  This is a browser security feature.  You should be able to find loads of info/questions about CORS to help you further.

Comment: Hi Dan, thank you very much for your answer. I really helped me! I set up the CORS in the Spring boot service at heroku and now is possible to make the axios call :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve it by changing the Cors configuration at the spring service

```
@Bean
    public WebMvcConfigurer corsConfigurer() {
        return new WebMvcConfigurerAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
                registry.addMapping("/**")
                        .allowedMethods("HEAD", "GET", "PUT", "POST", "DELETE", "PATCH");
            }
        };
    }
```